# Replace values based on a list of special characters in python

Tags: python, arrays

this the list of special words or characters that i want to change.

```
special_patterns=['a','al','am','asi','b','ba','ba','bco','cion','d','da',
'dan','del','do','e','es','hd','imp','in','inr','int','inte',
'isc','le','lo','man','me','mensual','mes','muy','n','no','o',
'ok','par','pc','pm','pro','r','ra','s','se','si','sr','sra','sub',
'ta','tel''tel','tv','va','ver','vola','ximo'
]
```

I tried to did with for loop but is not working

```
for a in range(len(special_patterns)):
    df['COMENTARIO_PALABRAS'] =df['COMENTARIO_PALABRAS'].str.replace(r'\b'+special_patterns[a]+'\b','',regex=True)
```

i also tried other versions like:

```
df['COMENTARIO_PALABRAS'] =df['COMENTARIO_PALABRAS'].str.replace(r'\b'+'|'.join(new_patterns)+'\b', '',regex=True)
```

and still not work. Could you help me pls

Comment: Can you please provide a small code to setup an example dataframe?

Comment: Your regex in the last code example will look like `\ba|al|am\b`, whereas it needs to be like `\b(a|al|am)\b`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
pat = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(special_patterns) + r')\b'

df['COMENTARIO_PALABRAS'] = df['COMENTARIO_PALABRAS'].str.replace(pat, "", regex=True)
```

Test/Output :

```
print(df)

    COMENTARIO_PALABRAS (before)    COMENTARIO_PALABRAS (after)
0  foo like a, baz asi, and tel.         foo like , baz , and .
1        b, ba, and r in the bar              , , and   the bar
```